# add items to ArrayAdapter<String>

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I feel like this question has been asked a million times, and answered a million times.  I've read and reviewed a dozen answers and I still can't get this to work.  It seems very simple to me, but I've spent a pretty long time on it and I'm only seeing the first item of my array-adapter no matter what I do.  I expect I'm missing something really simple, but mostly the examples I'm finding show this is the way to do it, so I'm baffled.

```
    result  = (ListView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.resultesult );

    resultAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 );
    resultAdapter.add( "one" );
    resultAdapter.clear();
    resultAdapter.add( "two" );
    resultAdapter.add( "three" );

    result.setAdapter( resultAdapter );
```

When I run my program, the ListView seems only to contain "two."  The .count() is 2, like I'd expect ("two" and "three" after the .clear()), but the ListView is only showing "two."  Even if I add a thousand items at run time, it'll just show "two."  If I .clear() it, then it shows the first thing I .add(), but I'd really like to show everything I add, not just the first one.

This is a really short snipped that makes no sense like this.  In my actual program I'm doing .add("blah") and then .notifyDataSetChanged() under .post()s after various things happen; but I get the same results there too.

UPDATE1: My layout (as requested by comment) is as follows.  The layout seemed to work fine when the ListView was a TextView instead.  I did wonder after I asked if it just wasn't expanding into the ScrollView or something.  I should have posted it in the first place.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/command"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/commandHint"
    android:imeActionId="@+id/execCommand"
    android:imeActionLabel="@string/exec"
    android:imeOptions="actionSend"
    android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete|textMultiLine|textUri"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="false"
    android:typeface="monospace" >

</AutoCompleteTextView>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/command"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal|vertical"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</ScrollView>
```

UPDATE2: Per a couple of answers below, I tried this with an arraylist, and it didn't make any difference.

```
    result  = (ListView) rootView.findViewById( R.id.resultesult );

    ArrayList<String> doubtThisllMatter = new ArrayList<String>();
    doubtThisllMatter.add( "one" );
    doubtThisllMatter.add( "two" );
    doubtThisllMatter.add( "three" );

    resultAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, 
          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
          doubtThisllMatter );

    result.setAdapter( resultAdapter );
```

I still just get "one" in the list displayed in the activity.

Comment: Could your post your layout xml plz? I think there may be something wrong with it.

Comment: Ahh, posting the layout was key.  It was putting a scroller inside a scroller.  I had the scrollview initially because the listview used to be a textview.  ugh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please remove the ScrollView. Using ListView inside ScrollView is not allowed. Because ListView by default has Scrolling effect.

Answer (score 2):

```
protected ArrayList<String> arrayStrings = new ArrayList<String>();

arrayStrings.add("One");
arrayStrings.add("Two");
arrayStrings.add("Three");

resultAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout. simple_list_item_1, arrayStrings)

result.setAdapter( resultAdapter );
```

Comment: I don't actually have the list yet.  I get the items later.  The snippet was just an example of something I'd expect to work.  Are you saying I should update the array passed to the adapter instead?  I may not understand.

Comment: yes first you have to add value in to arrayList or array whatever you ll take and then pass it to arrayAdapter

Comment: I don't think that's right.  I mean, I obviously don't know, but I don't think so.  How do you pass the arraylist to the adapter? Isn't it already adapting it?  Isn't .add() the way you pass new values to the adapted array?

Comment: yeah it already arrayadpater ,but thats means you have to pass value of data which has type " Array or ArrayList" so you have to pass value in the form of it ,, i have no option rather than passing value in the form of Array of ArrayList so use it and njoy

Comment: OK, I've done it by passing in the arraylist rather than using the one built into the adapter.  See update. It made no difference.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Create a global ArrayList and add the contents to it using `add()` and pass it to ArrayAdapter. It's better to pass the `List` or `String[]` to `ArrayAdapter` and set that adapter to `List` You should update the List or Array being passed to Adapter, not Adapter itself.

```
ArrayList<String> myList ;


myList = new ArrayList<String>;

myList.add("ONE");       // add items to List
myList.add("TWO");
myList.add("THREE");
myList.add("FOUR");



ArrayAdapter<String> ad = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, myList);  // pass List to ArrayAdapter

yourListView.setAdapter(ad);   // set the adapter to ListView.
```

**EDIT**

Please remove the `ScrollView`. Using `ListView` inside `ScrollView` is not allowed. Because ListView by default has Scrolling effect.

Comment: I don't have the list or array yet.  It comes in later.  The snippet is just an example of something I'd expect to work.

Comment: You should update the Array passed to Adapter. When you get the items, add it to Array or List then pass it to Adapter.

Comment: I don't think that's right. I mean, I obviously don't know, but I don't think so. How do you pass the arraylist to the adapter? Isn't it already adapting it? Isn't .add() the way you pass new values to the adapted array?

Comment: No, you are wrong. Please read about it. I have written a comment where I passed the ArrayList to Adapter. Do check everything. This is the proper way to do it.

Comment: OK, I've done it by passing in the arraylist rather than using the one built into the adapter.  See update. It made no difference.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Remove the ScrollView. You shouldn't use ListView inside ScrollView.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  The ListView used to be a TextView.  I just changed it without even looking that up.  So that was super easy to fix apparently.  Note that you do *not* need to pass an array of any kind to the adapter.  It does indeed have one built in; but you can't see anything but the first element if you put a scroller inside a scroller.  /note

Please submit the remove scroller as an answer so I can checkmark you as a correct answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer by adding about ScrollView. Please check

Comment: Well, most of the answer is misleading and incorrect.  I'm more inclined to select Leog's answer below as the correct one.  That's why I was hoping you'd submit it as a new answer.  I guess I can, ... yeah, you can move the checkmark.  I can select his for now and move it later.  He was the only one to ask about the layout anyway.

Comment: I just left it as new answer :D

Answer (score 1):

After you post your layout, the reason why you met that problem is obvious: you put the ListView inside a ScrollView. So remove the ScrolllView and set the ListView to take up enough space must solve you problem. I'm happy to know that you have solved it yourself.^^

Answer (score 0):

According to your question, you get the data later.

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter resultAdapter;

// Inside onCreate() or any other method.
//Currently List is empty
resultAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout. simple_list_item_1, arrayList)
result.setAdapter( resultAdapter );
```

//More Code...

//Let say you have data now in your arraylist after some scenario, a service call maybe
//After adding data in your arraylist, simply call notifydatasechanged

```
resultAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Yeah, I said that in the main body of the question (though, it's fairly well buried at this point).  I totally use notifyDataSetChanged() in the real code, but the snippet should work like it is.  In UPDATE2, I even pre-populate an arraylist, and I still just get the first element.

I think it's more of a layout problem at this point.  I'm looking at that right now.